# How to get the AppData path

Tags: c++, winapi

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL,buffer, CSIDL_APPDATA,FALSE );
```

> `C:\Users\guest\AppData\Roaming`

```
SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(NULL,buffer, CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA,FALSE );
```

> `C:\Users\guest\AppData\Local`

Is there way to get the path `C:\Users\guest\AppData` using windows API's?

Comment: I want to avoid any folders which comes under Appdata. ie, if user selecteds any folder under AppaData, I have to skip thoses.

Comment: Another question asked by HPFE455 today was looking for a Temp folder on Win7. If this is related to the same project, SHGetSpecialFolderPath is deprecated since Vista. Searching the MSDN documentation will answer this and many related questions.

Answer (score 3):

The roaming and local folders exist for a reason, sometimes you might need to put something in the root of the profile but you are not really supposed to do it. This is what MSDN says about CSIDL_PROFILE:

> Applications should not create files or folders at this level; they
>   should put their data under the locations referred to by CSIDL_APPDATA
>   or CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA. However, if you are creating a new Known
>   Folder the profile root referred to by CSIDL_PROFILE is appropriate.

On NT5 they don't even have the same parent folder and "Roaming" is in the root of the profile:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data
```

The user and/or domain admin can move and/or redirect those folders to anywhere, to the root of a different drive or a network share.

The only documented way I can think of to find the parent is to use [IKnownFolderManager::GetFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761738%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then call `IKnownFolder::GetFolderDefinition` and look at `KNOWNFOLDER_DEFINITION.fidParent` (Keep in mind that there does not have to be a parent, IKnownFolderManager::Redirect takes a string as the target so a redirected folder can be anywhere)

If you want to exclude files under a special shell folder you should compare the path with something like [PathCommonPrefix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [IKnownFolderManager::FindFolderFromPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761718%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).